# When I click on my product it is redirected to Homepage using Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Here is the link which is redirected:
https://luxuryrosemilan.com/product/flowerbox-color-crema-con-6-rose-blu-eterne/

Answer (score 0):

Please give more details and ask specific questions that contains what you are trying to achieve and what is the result.

Comment: here you can see my product  link.   https://luxuryrosemilan.com/product/flowerbox-color-crema-con-6-rose-blu-eterne/    its redirected to home page.